# Can I make an Excel VBA macro available to all workbooks?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, vba

Is it possible to write a VBA script in one workbook, and use it in other workbooks in the machine? I guess I'm looking for a way to write a macro package.

**EDIT**
Following the instruction in the link given by Lance, I managed to create the addin, but I cannot see it in the 'Macros' tab. What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, here's [one link](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-add-in-create.htm) that explains how to create an Excel Addin with VBA code.  You can also create other types of addins in other ways, but this is the simplest.  There are thousands of references you can search for that talk about how to do this.

Comment: doesn't answer the question at all

Comment: @johnywhy Yes, an addin is something available to all workbooks. And if you read the question you'll see the OP used my link to do that.

Comment: i misread the question. Addin macros can be executed from the Macro ribbon. But, addin VBA functions aren't visible to other VBA projects in the VBA IDE -- they aren't listed in the Object Browser.

Answer (score 17):

## No addon making required!

Store it in a special workbook called `Personal.xlsb`

### Steps:

You can make macros available across all your workbooks, by saving them to a special workbook that Excel loads each time it is opened.

- YouTube : [**How to Create a Personal Macro Workbook in Excel and Why You Need It**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rD2-mSbTuL0)
- Office Support : [**Create and save all your macros in a single workbook**](https://support.office.com/article/create-and-save-all-your-macros-in-a-single-workbook-66c97ab3-11c2-44db-b021-ae005a9bc790)
- Office Support : [**Copy your macros to a Personal Macro Workbook**](https://support.office.com/article/copy-your-macros-to-a-personal-macro-workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566)

Comment: This is good only if other users does not have their own set of VBA codes in that .xlsb file. I have not tested what will happen if Sub name clash between multiple .xlsb file in XLSTART folder

Comment: @PatricK Of course not. It works with multiple users in a windows machine. Each user gets their own `XLSTART` folder. Notice that path to `XLSTART` looks like `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART` . Since there is a Username, its different for each user

Comment: The linked video has been deleted. I'm editing the answer to remove it. Feel free to add a new link if you have one.

Comment: @AndyMercer thanks for editing the answer. The content on the web is so ephemeral. Hopefully, the `personal.xlsb` hint allows people to figure it out with the help of google. I shall update the answer if I happen to do this again.

Answer (score 2):

Take advantage of the UserProfile environment variable to aviod that 'different for each user' caveat.

so the standardized Path is:
   %UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART

Answer (score 2):

When you record a Macro you can store it afterwards in your Personal Macro Workbook. When you Exit Excel it asks if you want to store it, once you click yes the Macro will become available for all workbooks under Developer => Macros. See also [Microsoft support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-your-macros-to-a-Personal-Macro-Workbook-AA439B90-F836-4381-97F0-6E4C3F5EE566)

Answer (score 1):

**How to locate the XLStart folder**

-1.Click the Microsoft Office Button  Office button image , and then click Excel Options.
-2.Click Trust Center, and then under Microsoft Office Excel Trust Center, click Trust Center Settings.
-3.Click Trusted Locations, and then verify the path to the XLStart folder in the list of trusted locations.

Comment: ...or, just hit the Windows key and type `XLSTART`.